# django.contrib.auth get_user_model isn't working with monitio app

Tags: python, django

i have to set up some big project to start working on it, but i don't have access to its creator, so i have nobody to ask.

This project make use of [monitio app](https://github.com/mpasternak/django-monitio) to handle notifications.

And i got this error:

```
File "******/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/monitio/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
ImportError: cannot import name get_user_model
```

I have no idea, why it isn't working, since there is everything installed. Maybe i miss something related to virtualenv or something.
I suppose that maybe in some weird way monitio has not access to django.contrib.auth or smthg.
Anyway im lost.

Every piece of advice will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Django >= 1.5? I think <=1.4 don't have a `get_user_model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be its because of your Django version problem,

Which Django version your using?

In requirements.txt of Django-monitio said that they are using django>=1.6. And also see the other requirements in the requirements.txt

Comment: That was it, Django version, i miss the fact that in requirements was other django version, that i thought.