# Django: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_user_model' from 'django.contrib.auth.models'

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-authentication

I have a problem using Djangos Default user `from django.contrib.auth.models` but trying to use it with my custom User model, using `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`.

Following those articles:

- [Django
  Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends)
- [Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/best-practices-for-starting-a-django-project-with-the-right-user-model-290a09452b88)
- [SimpleIsBetter
  1](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)
- [SimpleIsBetter
  2](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

So here is my User model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# from django.conf import settings
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
# https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries


class User(AbstractUser):
    """auth/login-related fields"""
    is_a = models.BooleanField('a status', default=False)
    is_o = models.BooleanField('o status', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

and here is my Profile model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField # https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries
from django.contrib.auth.models import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
# https://medium.com/swlh/best-practices-for-starting-a-django-project-with-the-right-user-model-290a09452b88

from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver



class Profile(models.Model):
    """non-auth-related/cosmetic fields"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    nationality = CountryField(null=True)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

"""receivers to add a Profile for newly created users"""
@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created:
         Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

and in my `settings.py` I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mysite.User'`

`settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mysite.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mysite.apps.MysiteConfig',
    'django_countries',
    'djmoney',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

But when I'm trying to make my migrations i get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'get_user_model' from 'django.contrib.auth.models'`

And I've looked for answers but I'm only getting on topics speaking of Django needing to be version 1.5 or higher, and I'm using Django 3.0.2

The typical posts i find is this:

- [StackOverflow
  1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497883/cannot-import-name-get-user-model)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3j3oj8/importerror_cannot_import_name_user/)
- [StackOverflow
  2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471735/global-name-get-user-model-is-not-defined)
- [StackOverflow
  3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405240/django-contrib-auth-get-user-model-isnt-working-with-monitio-app)

Does anyone know what am I missing? or doing wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

Here is my User views, with my User serializers:

`views_user.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ..models.model_user import *
from ..serializers.serializers_user import *


class UserIndex(generics.ListAPIView):
    """List all users, or create a new user."""

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = UserIndexSerializer

class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """List all art pieces, or create a new art piece."""

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer

class UserDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """Retrieve, update or delete a user instance."""

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
```

`serializers_user.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ..models.model_user import *


class UserIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'age',
            # 'nationality',
            'gender',
            'profession'
        ]

class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'profession'
        ]

class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: The second SO link has your answer. It's `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`

Comment: I updated my post with my views and serializers, but i was importing it wrong, had `.models` in `from django.contrib.auth.models import get_user_model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import in the Profile model `from django.contrib.auth.models import get_user_model`
 is wrong.

You should do `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`, note there is no `.models` at the end.

According to documentation and examples in Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Comment: Thank you @ceorcham! It did the trick, it was my bad, don't know why i added `.models`.